# How to make Statusbar not transparent(Android 5)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles, android-coordinatorlayout, android-statusbar

I'm using a CoordinatorLayout and this(`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`) line of code in order the hide the toolbar whenever a RecyclerView is scrolled. And this also works pretty well, but the Toolbar does not get hidden behind the Statusbar because it is transparent.

My layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.yannisbecker.backup.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:src="@drawable/ic_backup_white_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Since I already searched up the internet and only found a lot of things about "How to make the Statusbar transparent" I'm now asking here and hope somebody can help me.

Because I don't have enought reputation, yet, you can find an image the shows my Problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u63b4.png)

Comment: You need to post the XML layout code.

Comment: I've added the layout now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the toolbar under the status bar when recycler-view is scrolled, then you've to change the color of the status-bar to your liking and also remove this attribute: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `<CoordinatorLayout>` tag.

Setting the color of the status bar can be done in the MainActivity by using `getWindow.setStatusBarColor()` method :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
   }
```

or

Add or edit, if present, this tag in the styles.xml file in `AppTheme.NoActionBar` style

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/color_of_your_choice</item>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me alot